# MouseLeave not fired C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mouseleave

I have a user control with 2 buttons, that should only be visible when the mouse is inside the area of the control.

I'm showing the buttons like this:

```
private void Node_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    btn1.Show();
    btn2.Show();
}
```

And hiding like this:

```
protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.ClientRectangle.Contains(this.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)))
        return;
    else base.OnMouseLeave(e);
}

private void Node_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    btn1.Hide();
    btn2.Hide();
}
```

The problem is that sometimes (random situations) the `MouseLeave` event is not fired, and the buttons stay visible, even with the mouse outside the control.

Is it possible that multiple events get in conflict ?

Comment: Can you set a break point to verify that the event is literally not firing? Or are you basing that on observed behavior?

Comment: The observed behavior shows that, and i'm doing some debugging (printing to the console) that confirms the situation.

Comment: I've tested your code with and without OnMouseLeave and in both cases it worked just fine. Why are you doing additional check in overriden OnMouseLeave method? It's not necessary here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we change event routing strategy in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561267/can-we-change-event-routing-strategy-in-windows)

Comment: @virious it works fine in most cases. But i have several controls with that events and sometimes when i'm moving the mouse over them, the `MouseLeave`event is not fired. So, it happens to exist several controls with the buttons visible, while the mouse isn't over none of them.

Comment: @virious If I dont override the `OnMouseLeave` event, the buttons dont stay enabled to click.

Answer (score 2):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561267/can-we-change-event-routing-strategy-in-windows) link states:

> *Mouse move messages are not accurate enough, they don't guarantee that every traversed pixel is reported. When you have a child window close to the edge of its parent, it is quite easy to not get the MouseEnter for the parent when you move the mouse fast enough.*

So, the solution was to listen only for the `MouseEnter`event, and when this event is fired, i send a notification to the other controls, to hide its buttons.

Is not the most elegant solution, but it works as expected.