# Why does my code not execute past PointToScreen or RectangleToScreen etc. in a timer?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have created a custom control which should fade in when the mouse enters and out if the mouse leaves.

To obtain this functionality I tried to add a timer which starts upon `MouseEnter` that monitors the mouse position. As is pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230257/mouseleave-not-fired-c-sharp-winforms) post, the `MouseLeave` event doesn't trigger reliably enough, and it is especially the case with the way my form is laid out.

In my timer the current cursor position is supposed to be translated relative to the client with this code:

```
Point mPos = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

When I add a break point on that line, the debugger breaks there. If I try step through the code, everything just seems to be stuck in a loop and the code keeps returning to that point.

Any break point after that line is never reached but the rest of the non-timer code still seem to execute flawlessly.

If I replace the problem line with any other code everything executes normally, the error is specifically at the screen to client transforms.

The timer code is shown below:

```
private void FadeTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Point mPos = PointToClient(Cursor.Position);//Execution never passes this line. No exceptions are thrown
    if (ClientRectangle.Contains(mPos))//Execution never reaches this point
        fade = fade + 20 <= 255 ? fade + 20 : 255;
    else
        fade = fade - 20 >= 100 ? fade - 20 : 100;          
    this.Invalidate();
    this.Refresh();
}
```

I have tried transforming the client rectangle to screen coordinates with `RectangleToScreen` and the same error happens.

> Will you please tell me why this happens and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: You have to call this from the UI thread with Invoke

Comment: This is technically possible when you haven't upgraded to VS2015 yet and run your code in 64-bit mode.  The legacy x64 jitter generates bad debugging info for *some* statements, it is especially apt to do so for expressions that use the conditional operator.  Using a breakpoint isn't the right way to debug this kind of highly interactive code anyway, the context switch when the breakpoint is hit gets in the way.  Using the remote debugger is a workaround but a bit heavy, much easier to temporarily add a Debug.WriteLine() statement to show the value of *fade* in the Output window.

Comment: @philippe your comment works like a charm. Thanks